# How can I dynamically update the bound of a for loop with OpenMP ic C?

Tags: c, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

I am building a parallel version of a program that I initially wrote in a serial fashion. This function reads a file to create the input vector needed for following operations. Since OpenMP particularly likes for loops, I converted what was initially a while loop into this, that basically is a "dynamic" for loop, where the upper bound (limit?) of the loop is continuously updated until the file is over.

As a serial code, this works with no issues, even on very big files (1M+ lines). However, when I implement the OMP pragmas, it won't work. From my troubleshooting it appears that using the omp pragmas the upper bound (vec_size) cannot be dynamically updated. Is there a work-around for this issue? Thank you in advance.

```
int readfile(double complex** vec, char* filepath)
{
FILE* filePointer;
char line[50] = {0};
filePointer = fopen(filepath,"r");
double complex* v;
int n=0, i=0, vec_size=VEC_SIZE;                        //number of elements in the vector

v = malloc(VEC_SIZE*sizeof(complex));
//read file and store elements in vec
float tmp;

#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp for ordered 
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    #pragma omp ordered
    fgets(line, 50, filePointer);
    printf("for %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    
    if(n==(vec_size-1) && !feof(filePointer)){              //check if size is exceeded
        printf("if %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
        vec_size=2*vec_size;                
        v = realloc(v, vec_size*sizeof(complex));           //double initial allocated space
        printf("vec_size if %d\n", vec_size);
    }
    printf("vec_size for %d\n", vec_size);
    sscanf(line,"%f",&tmp);
    v[n] = tmp + 0*I;
    n++;
}
}
fclose(filePointer);
*vec = v;
return n;
}
```

Comment: Your loop is totally sequential. You cannot parallelize it using OpenMP. What do you expect the OpenMP runtime to do with a `omp ordered` put in a parallel section? More generally reading a given file is not a task that can be parallelized on most platforms. Note that parsing could be parallelized, but in this case, `fgets` will certainly be the bottleneck. Note that `v` cannot be safely set by a thread at runtime in the parallel loop because it is shared and other threads are working on it causing a *race-condition*.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I see how a file read is unlikely to be made parallel but thought I'd give it a shot anyways. I guess I'll let this function be sequential with the original while construct then